# Callable Bond = long Bond - call on bond?

Tags: options, bond, call

Can someone verify (maybe there is some literature around) the following relationships?

1. Callable Bond= Long on Bond + short on a Call Position 
   -->

**PV(CallableBond) = PV(Bond) - Call on Bond?**

or state differently:

**PV(Bond) - PV(Callable Bond) = Call on Bond?**

2. Since a Receiver Swaption equals a Call on a Bond following should be true?

**PV(Bond) - PV(Callable Bond) = ReceiverSwaption?**

Maybe someone can provide me with some literature regarding this Topic.

Thanks,

K.S.

Comment: These are correct, except in swaption pricing the counterparty risk is often handled differently, and in bond pricing we often think about credit risk (stochastically varying or deterministic)